Getting error from docker daemon while testing the GitHub Actions workflows locally using act
Getting error "Error: failed to create container: 'Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: '/opt/hostedtoolcache' " while testing the GitHub Actions workflows locally using act.
I am trying to run command "act -P =<docker_image>" but it's giving above error on one laptop & on another laptop it is working fine.
How can I fix this error?
